# JQGrid Select Row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a custom checkbox column on my JQGrid, each time the user clicks on the checkbox I would like to display all the row information in a message box.

My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tonymaloney1971/rk7b1dbx/5/):

I have tried the following, but does nothing:

```
function getCurrentBinRow() {
       var grid = $('#grid'),
           selRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
           celValue = grid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Inv No');
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use simple `formatter: "checkbox"` with `formatoptions: { disabled: false }` and use `beforeSelectRow` to detect changing of the checkbox:

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this),
        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0]),
        cm = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel"),
        localData = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid);
    if (cm[iCol].name === "MyPrint" && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {
        // set local grid data
        localData.MyPrint = $(e.target).is(":checked");
        alert(JSON.stringify(localData));
    }

    return true; // allow selection
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/rk7b1dbx/9/. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) on very close question.