# Unable to handle checkbox click event in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for some purpose. In this grid there are 6 columns in which last columns is just integer value (NoLicense-available license count) and last 2nd is checkbox.

I want to make following functionality using this grid.

1. If checkbox is tick then value of NoLicense must be NoLicense++;

   2  if the same checkbox is untick then value of NoLicense must be NoLicense--;
2. If NoLicense=0 then alert('License exhausted');

Below is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: param,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        try {
            var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            $(this).MessageBox('error', msg.Message);
        }
        catch (e) {
            $(this).MessageBox('error', xhr.responseText);
        }
        return false;
        $(this).HideBusy();
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var xmlString = data.d;
        if (xmlString != '') {
            $("#AvailableLicense").jqGrid({
                ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/xml; charset=utf-8' },
                datatype: 'xmlstring',
                datastr: xmlString,
                xmlReader: { root: "AvailableLicenses", row: "row", repeatitems: false, id: "ItemCode" },
                colNames: ['Code', 'Name', 'Profile Name', 'Expires On', 'Used', 'Available'],
                colModel: [

                            { name: 'ItemCode', index: 'TenantConfID', align: "left", width: 40 },
                            { name: 'Itemname', index: 'ObjectTypeID', align: "left", width: 40 },
                            { name: 'ProfileName', index: 'CRMObjectTypeID', align: "left", width: 20 },
                            { name: 'EndDate', index: 'SAPObjectTypeID', align: "left", width: 40, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y/m/d', newformat: 'd-m-Y'} },
                            { name: 'Used', index: 'Used', align: "center", width: 20, editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: 'checkbox',
                                editoptions: { value: "1:0", readonly: false }
                            },
                            { name: 'U_NoUsers', index: 'SAPObjectText', align: "center", width: 40 }
                         ],
                onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
                    UserRowID = $("#ClientUsers").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    debugger;
                    if (UserRowID != null) {
                        selectedRowId = $("#AvailableLicense").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        $('#AvailableLicense').jqGrid('editRow', selectedRowId, true);
                        var $target = $(e.target), $td = $target.closest("td"),
                        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
                        colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
                        if (iCol >= 0 && $target.is(":checkbox")) {
                            var Count = $("#AvailableLicense").jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'U_NoUsers');
                            var Used = $("#AvailableLicense").jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId, 'Used');
                            if (Used == '1') {
                                if (Count > 0) {
                                    Count = Count - 1;
                                    var rowData = $('#AvailableLicense').jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);
                                    rowData.U_NoUsers = Count;
                                    $('#AvailableLicense').jqGrid('setRowData', selectedRowId, rowData);
                                }
                                else
                                    $(this).MessageBox('error', 'License Exhausted');
                            }
                            else {
                                Count = Count + 1;
                                var rowData = $('#AvailableLicense').jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);
                                rowData.U_NoUsers = Count;
                                $('#AvailableLicense').jqGrid('setRowData', selectedRowId, rowData);

                            }


                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                        $(this).MessageBox('error', 'Please select user first');
                },
                rowNum: 10,
                mtype: 'POST',
                pager: "#AvailableLicenseMap",
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                loadonce: true, forceFit: true,
                width: 600,
                height: 250,
                caption: 'Available License'
            }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#AvailableLicenseMap', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false }); //.trigger('reloadGrid') ;

        }
    }
});
```

But I found that rowselectevent does not works properly when I tick the checkbox.
1. When I select the first row event fires.
2. When I reselect the same row it does not fire.
3. After selecting the row If I change the value of checkbox, it doesn't fire event.

May be I don't understand it properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to me that you could simplify your code by usage `formatoptions: { disabled: false }` in the column `'Used'` having `formatter: 'checkbox'`. In the case you don't need to use any editing mode at all. To make actions on checking/unckecking of the checkbox from the column `'Used'` one can use `beforeSelectRow` callback. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox.htm) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935). The demo tests for the click inside of the column `closed` (you need change `closed` to `Used` of cause). To make some actions in case of clicking on the checkboxs only one need to change the line `if (cm[iCol].name === "closed") {` to `if (cm[iCol].name === "Used" && e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "INPUT") {`