# JQGRID can't get cell value for ajax parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I try to inline update a specify cell's row of jQgrid.
i send the parameter using ajax.
i could get for id value, but i have difficulty to get cell value from a column named `Status`. My code below seems not working.

```
{name:'Status', index:'Status', width:50,search:true,align : 'center',
 editable: true,edittype:"checkbox",editoptions: {value:"OK:"}, 
 stype:'text',searchoption:{sopt:['cn']}}

loadComplete: function () {
   var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this),'Status'),rows = this.rows,i,c = rows.length;
   for (i = 1; i < c; i += 1) {
      $(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
         var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id,isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
         var rowData = jQuery("#list").getRowData(id);
         var colData = rowData['Status'];    

         $.ajax({
                 type   : "POST",
                 url    : "process1.php",
                 async  : false,
                 cache  : false,
                 data   : "id="+id+"&Status="+colData+"&action=cekmark",
                 success: function() {
                     $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
                     return this;
                     }
                 });
           return false;
           });
      }
  }
```

this is ajax result:

```
id:50831
Status:
action:cekmark
```

try to use the answer below

```
var rowData = jQuery("#list").getRowData(id);
var colData = rowData.Status;
```

found after click at selected cell (checkbox not yet show) but ajax directly send the parameter to server.why?

---

**ANSWER**

Based on oleg answer i change some script which suitable with my case :

```
onCellSelect: function () {
   var iCol = getColumnIndexByName($(this),'Status'),rows = this.rows,i,c = rows.length;
   for (i = 1; i < c; i += 1) {
      $(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(function (e) {
          var id = $(e.target).closest('tr')[0].id,isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');
          var isChecked = isChecked? "OK" : "";
          $.ajax({
             type   : "POST",
             url    : "process1.php",
             async  : false,
             cache  : false,
             data   : "id="+id+"&Status="+isChecked+"&action=cekmark",
             success: function() {
                $("#list").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid'); //this make your grid reloaded without reload page
                //$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid"); 
                return this;
                }
             });
         return false;
         });
      }
    }
```

Comment: are you returning status from the server?? I mean have you assigned anything to the "Status" key in the json which you are returning from the server?

Comment: @Krishna Status value is "OK". i try the second way but value is `false` so ajax send wrong data.

Comment: I think you should assign boolean value to the "Status" key! Can you post the server code to which you are making the ajax request? @nunu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you use `jQuery("#list").getRowData(id)['Status']`. The value of `isChecked` variable get you the required results already. So to solve your main problem you can just use

```js
data: "id="+id+"&Status="+isChecked+"&action=cekmark",
```

or, event better,

```js
data: {id: id, Status: isChecked, action: "cekmark" },
```

One more advice. You register **multiple** `click` event handler inside of `loadComplete`. Every `<input type="checkbox" ...>` will get his own `click` event handler. I would recommend you to use **one existing** `click` handler registered by jqGrid in the whole body of the grid. It calls `beforeSelectRow` is you use the handle. [The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) provides [the demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935) which do very close to all what you need. You need just make small modifications and include `$.ajax` call to inform the server about changing of the checkbox state.

Comment: i try to remove formatter, cause for my case i need basic checkbox edit. after use your answer i found that after (single) click there is nothing happen(checkbox not show).but if double click (checkbox still not show) ajax send to server with `Status:false`.

Comment: @nunu: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Do you tried to use `data: "id="+id+"&Status="+isChecked+"&action=cekmark"` instead of `data   : "id="+id+"&Status="+colData+"&action=cekmark"` first of all? Do you tried [the demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935), which do some actions (it implements local editing) on changing Status state? Do you really need to use `edittype:"checkbox"``and not `formatter:"checkbox"`? The `loadComplete` will be executed only after formatter fills the grid, but no row is in editing now, so the code `$(rows[i].cells[iCol]).click(.)` will not work.

Comment: i have tried to change `colData into isChecked` the parameter can send. then i want to know what is the value of `isChecked`, i call `alert(isChecked);` and now i get isChecked value is `true` not `OK` . why?

Comment: @nunu: because `isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');`. So it have Boolean value. You can use `isChecked? "OK" : ""` instead if you want.

Comment: for my case i change `beforeSelectRow` into `onCellSelect`.

Comment: @nunu: OK! The only advantage of `beforeSelectRow` is that can be used to prevent row selection. For example you can have selected one row and the user click on "button" or checkbox of another row. Inside of `beforeSelectRow` you can implement reaction on the "button" or checkbox *without* changing which row is selected. If selection of rows is not important then `onCellSelect` would be the best choice probably.