# how to get selected checkbox row id in jq grid with editable checkbox

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
  var data = [[48803,"true"], [48769,"true"]];

      $("#grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        height: 250,
        colNames: ['Inv No','MyPrint'],
        colModel: [{
            name: 'id',
            index: 'id',
            width: 60,
            sorttype: "int"},
      {
            name: 'MyPrint',
            index: 'MyPrint',
            width: 80,
            editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
            editrules: { required: true },
            edittype: 'checkbox',
            formatter: myPrintCheckboxFormatter,
            formatoptions: { disabled: false },
            editable: true  }    
        ],
        caption: "test example"
    });

    var names = ["id","true"];
    var mydata = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        mydata[i] = {};
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
            mydata[i][names[j]] = data[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (var i = 0; i <= mydata.length; i++) {
        $("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
    }

    function myPrintCheckboxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
//how to pass currently selcted id of row
        return "<input type='checkbox' name='MyPrint' onchange='getCurrentBinRow()'>";
    }

    function getCurrentBinRow() {
        /*here I want to get the current selected MyPrint row*/

 var id= $('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');  // id  becomes null  
   }
```

How to retrive selected row id ?,i have tried but getting null.
I   does not understand how to pass it from onchange event javascript function   getCurrentBinRow.i want to  pass checked and unchecked status to server and if you checked the css of row need to background red and after unchecked css need to at row

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function myPrintCheckboxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' name='MyPrint' onchange='getCurrentBinRow(this)'>";
} //---------------------------------------------------pass this in here-----^^^^

function getCurrentBinRow(elem) {
    var id = $(elem).closest('tr')[0].id;
    $(elem).closest('tr').toggleClass('redRow'); // adds red bgcolor when checked.
    alert(id);  
}
```

add this css in your stylesheet:

```
.redRow{ background:red !important; }
```

#### Update:

You can even do this too:

You have `options` param in the custom formatter where you have `rowId` available in it. so you can pass `options.rowId` in the onchange function.

```
function myPrintCheckboxFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "<input type='checkbox' name='MyPrint' onchange='getCurrentBinRow(" + options.rowId + ")'>";
} //-------------------------------------------------------pass this in here-----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

function getCurrentBinRow(rowid) {
    alert(rowid);  
}
```

Comment: how to make css of background color to red if checked and if unchecked converted to normal css

Comment: You can make a new css class like `.redRow{background:red !important;}` and then within the first answer you can use `.toggleClass()` to add/remove the class.

Comment: @govindaghimre you can now check the answer updated. first part you can see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend you to use custom formatter to add the column with checkboxs. The predefined `formatter: "checkbox"` do this already. If you use `formatoptions: { disabled: false}` then the checkboxs are enabled. To implement some action on click on the checkbox it's not the best to use `onchange='getCurrentBinRow()` on **every checkbox**. Event bubbling allows to register **one event handler** only on a parent of the all checkboxes. It could be `tbody` or `table`. jqGrid register already onclick event handler on the table and allows to use `beforeSelectRow` and `onCellSelect` callbacks (`jqGridBeforeSelectRow` or `jqGridCellSelect` events) to implement some custom action. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox1.htm) or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox.htm), created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935), demonstrates the approach. It's the way which I would recommend you.

The last comment. The code example which you posted is *really very bad*. You should use `data: mydata` option of jqGrid to create the grid with the specified input data. Moreover one should use `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options additionally. Filling the grid by calling of `addRowData` in loop is the slowest way to fill the grid.