# How to implement single click checkbox in free jqGrid 4.13.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In free jqGrid before 4.13

```
editoptions: {
    disabled: false
},
```

Was used to implement single click checkbox in inline editing.
In 4.13 checkbox state is no more restored if clicked in new row without saving.

To reproduce, run code below and click in unchecked closed column to put checkmark into into it.
Now click in other row.
In 4.13 checkmark still appears in previous row.
Before 4.13 checkmark disappers.
How to fix this ?

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.extend(true, $.jgrid.defaults, {
            multiSort: true,
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center"
            },
            toppager: true,
            multiselect: true,
            scrollrows: true,
            loadui: 'block',
            cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true },
            autoencode: true,
            autoEncodeOnEdit: true,
            gridview: true
        });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            'use strict';
            var mydata = [
                    { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4", note: "note4", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5", note: "note5", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6", note: "note6", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7", note: "note7", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8", note: "note8", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9", note: "note9", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                    { id: "10", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true, ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "11", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                    { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
                $grid = $("#list")
            ;

            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: 'local',
                data: mydata,
                colModel: [
                    {
                        name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 80, align: 'center', editable: true
                    },
                    { name: 'name', index: 'name', editable: true, width: 65, editrules: { required: true } },
                    { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 75, editable: true },
                    { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 52, editable: true },
                    { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 60, editable: true },
                    {
                        template: "booleanCheckbox",
                        name: 'closed',
                        editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                            disabled: false
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ship_via', index: 'ship_via', width: 105, align: 'center', editable: true, formatter: 'select',
                        edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: 'FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim', defaultValue: 'IN' },
                        stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'], value: ':Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN' }
                    },
                    { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 60, sortable: false, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea' }
                ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                pager: '#pager',
                gridview: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                autoencode: true,
                ignoreCase: true,
                sortname: 'invdate',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: 'desc',
                height: '100%',
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                    var savedRow = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                    if (savedRow.length === 0 || savedRow[0] === undefined) {
                        $(this).jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true);
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (rowid !== savedRow[0].id) {
                        $grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', savedRow[0].id);
                        $(this).jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't understand **the goal of the usage of the property `disabled: false`** if the cell is editable. The state of the checkbox will be changed **before** `editRow` is started and unformat of the cell will return the value which is different as the value from original source data. As the result the data from the saved row (`p.savedRow`), which will be saved at the beginning of `editRow`, will hold *modified* state of the chanckbox instead of original state.

The option `disabled: false` of `formatter: "checkbox"` have sense very seldom if one want implement editing *without* starting any editing mode. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox.htm) (created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935)) or [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox1.htm) (created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29273406/315935)). The demos *modify* the local data on click on the checkbox and not uses any editing mode.

You should just remove the property because you want to edit the row using inline editing. The code which you use seems be wrong before, but probably the changes in version 4.13.0 made the bug visible.