# jqGrid randomly checks checkbox column

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for converting Json object into regular HTML table. From server I get object and everything is good except one thing. I have added one column that is actually checkbox column. In value attribute of each checkbox input I've put ID that later I am passing back to server if checkbox is checked.

```
$("#membersGrid").jqGrid({
    url: '/Member/GetAllMembers',
    mtype: "GET",
    styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
    datatype: "json",
    colModel: [
        { label: 'Full Name', name: 'fullName', width: 150 },
        {
            label: 'Select', editable: true, name: 'id',
            edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "true:false", defaultValue: "false" },
            formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }, width: 45
        }
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    height: 250,
    width: 640,
    rowNum: -1,
    ajaxSubgridOptions: { async: false },
});
```

When generating checkbox column for value I am defining true or false and with defaultValue I wanted to state that false(unchecked) is default value for each and every generated cell with checkbox.

But instead I am getting randomly checked check-boxes:

[image]

When I inspect element in Chrome, unchecked type is auto generated in this way:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="" aria-describedby="membersGrid_id">
     <input type="checkbox" value="400" offval="no">
</td>
```

And checked type like this:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="" aria-describedby="membersGrid_id">
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="399" offval="no">
</td>
```

Is there some other way to tell jqGrid to avoid checking checkboxes reather that using `defaultValue` attribute? Or I am doing something wrongly?

Comment: It seems that you use commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I can't help you with it, but I recommend you to try with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop. You need to change `styleUI: 'Bootstrap'` parameter to `guiStyle: "bootstrap"` (or `guiStyle: "bootstrapPrimary"`) (see [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap)) and to modify the URLs used to load jqGrid files to URLs of CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs))

Comment: If the same problem exists in free jqGrid 4.14.0, then I would need test JSON data returned from the server (`'/Member/GetAllMembers'`) to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for responding. I have noticed one interesting fact. When I remove name: 'id' attribute that basically defines value attribute of checkboxes, all checkboxes are unchecked. When I return it back it randomly checked again. I'm not sure how name attribute affects if checkbox is checked...

Comment: @Oleg P.S I will try with your version right away. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are exist misunderstanding about the usage of `formatter: "checkbox"`. It displays the input values `true` or `false` as checked/unchecked state of the checkbox. The property `id` of input data will be used as the **rowid**: the value of `id` attribute of the rows (`<tr>` elements of the grid).

Thus I recommend you to change the `name` or the column, which will hold the checkboxs. Your main problem should be fixed in the way.

I'd recommend you to be careful with the usage of `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }`. jqGrid supports three **editing modes**: cell editing, inline editing and form editing, which allows to modify the local data of jqGrid. Moreover you don't use `loadonce: true` option currently. Thus no local data will be created at all: only the data in the HTML table will hold the information returned from the server. The changes of the checkbox `formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: false }` will be not tracked and you could have problems with reading the data. All depend on *how* you read the data of the checkboxes... [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/EditableCheckbox1.htm), which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24239416/315935), shows how to modify *local* data of jqGrid so to save the state of the checkbox.